# How to write custom regular expression for url(custom url)

Tags: regex, validation

My application accepts the following type of URL

Example:

ABa12C.constant.com or

http://ABa12C.constant.com or

https://ABa12C.constant.com

1. (Optional)Starts with http:// or https:// or nothing.
2. Should not start with integer(1aAb4.constant.com is invalid).
3. In place of com it can be any like(in,uar,sr etc) but no integers.

My regular expression: [http://a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}.constant.[a-zA-Z]{1,5}

But how to make http:// optional and **can be used only at beginning** and cannot be integer at **beginning**.

Comment: Looks like you misuse character classes. What are you trying to do with `[http://a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}`? Try [`^(https?:\/\/)?[^0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,19}\.constant\.[a-zA-Z]{1,5}$`](https://regex101.com/r/wV7wW7/1)

Comment: ^ means checks at the start of string and ? means optional. But [^0-9] makes integer compulsory but i don't want integer at beginning.

Comment: You have not answered the question: what are you trying to achieve with `[http://a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}`? There is no any length restriction requirement listed in your question. Note that `[^0-9]` makes a **non-digit** compulsory.

Comment: Yes its working. So here ^ acting as start of string and also as exclude [0-9]. I mean does ^ character have two meanings in different locations.

Comment: I added a bit different answer - I guess you just wanted to match any ASCII letter there instead of any alphanumeric.

Comment: Yes both are working. Is this right{[^0-9] == [a-zA-Z]} .I just wanted to know what exactly [^0-9] mean. Is it mean starts with 0-9 or not 0-9 as you said ^ means start of string in other answer.

Comment: `[^0-9]` matches any character other than a digit. It matches `~`, `\n`, `*`, `a`, `_`, space. A lot of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern has no anchors, and the initial subpattern is a character class `[http://a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}` that matches 1 to 20 chars from the class, either `h` or `t`, `p`, `:`, `/`, `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` while you need to match `http://` as a *sequence*.

I suggest

```
^(https?:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,19}\.constant\.[a-zA-Z]{1,5}$
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wV7wW7/3)

**Explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(https?:\/\/)?` - an optional sequence of `http://` or `https://`
- `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,19}` - 0 to 19 alphanumeric characters (the length restriction can be adjusted by you)
- `\.constant\.` - a constant substring `.constant.`
- `[a-zA-Z]{1,5}` - 1 to 5 ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 0):

The following regex does the trick:

`(?:https?:\/\/)?[^0-9]\S*\.[^0-9]\S*` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tZ7mO0/1)

Note that a `non-capturing group (?:)` is used for the protocol.

Comment: It does not matter much if the group is capturing or not, but the `[^0-9]` will allow any symbol other than digits, while it seems OP needs only alphanumeric values in the input string.